# Substract time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, time

I have two fields 
beginning time and endingtime in a Mysql database. 
I want to calculate a duration inside a view in Laravel. 
So I wrote :

```
{{ $date1=date('G:i',strtotime($timeSlot->beginningTime)) }}
{{ $date2=date('G:i',strtotime($timeSlot->endingTime)) }}
{{ $date2-$date1 }}
```

My issue is : 
the difference gives me only hours difference without minutes...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to have logic inside a view.

**Use `carbon` and pass data from a  controller to the view.**

```
$date1 = Carbon::parse(date('G:i',strtotime($timeSlot->beginningTime)));
$date2 = Carbon::parse(date('G:i',strtotime($timeSlot->endingTime)));

$totalDuration = $date1->diffInSeconds($date2);
```

**Then use `gmdate`:**

```
   $exactDuration =  gmdate('H:i:s', $totalDuration);
```

// 00:00:21

You can then pass this `$exactDuration` to your view and use it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Carbon for that. Just tested, works perfectly:

```
$difference = Carbon::parse($timeSlot->beginningTime)->diff(Carbon::parse($timeSlot->endingTime));
```

In the view:

```
{{ $difference->h }}:{{ $difference->i }}
```

If you [cast dates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators), you don't even need to parse:

```
$difference = $timeSlot->beginningTime->diff($timeSlot->endingTime);
```